# Optimized Algorithm: Fastest Way to Derive Sets

Tags: algorithm, optimization, set

I'm writing a program for a competition and I need to be faster than all the other competitors. For this I need a little algorithm help; ideally I'd be using the fastest algorithm.

For this problem I am given 2 things. The first is a list of tuples, each of which contains exactly two elements (strings), each of which represents an item. The second is an integer, which indicates how many unique items there are in total. For example:

# of items = 3

[("ball","chair"),("ball","box"),("box","chair"),("chair","box")]

The same tuples can be repeated/ they are not necessarily unique.) My program is supposed to figure out the maximum number of tuples that can "agree" when the items are sorted into two groups. This means that if all the items are broken into two ideal groups, group 1 and group 2, what are the maximum number of tuples that can have their first item in group 1 and their second item in group 2.

For example, the answer to my earlier example would be 2, with "ball" in group 1 and "chair" and "box" in group 2, satisfying the first two tuples. I do not necessarily need know what items go in which group, I just need to know what the maximum number of satisfied tuples could be.

At the moment I'm trying a recursive approach, but its running on (n^2), far too inefficient in my opinion. Does anyone have a method that could produce a faster algorithm?

Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please format that text, that is unreadable even if one is interested and knows a solution

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand, the groups

Comment: this seems like the maximum bipartite subgraph problem, which is in NP.  are you allowed to reverse the order of edges or are they oriented?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Not quite though, as the link between two items is directional (for example ("box","chair") wants "box" in group 1 and "chair" in group 2 , however, ("chair","box") wants the reverse. Thus lines would need some kind of directional component to represent the data as a graph)

Answer (score 1):

Speed up approaches for your task:

**1. Use integers**

Convert the strings to integers (store the strings in an array and use the position for the tupples.

String[] words = {"ball", "chair", "box"};

In tuppls ball now has number 0 (pos 0 in array) , chair 1, box 2.
comparing ints is faster than Strings.

**2. Avoid recursion**

Recursion is slow, due the recursion overhead.
For example look at binarys search algorithm in a recursive implementatiion, then look how java implements `binSearch()` (with a while loop and iteration)

Recursion is helpfull if problems are so complex that a non recursive implementation is to complex for a human brain.

An iterataion is faster, but not in the case when you mimick recursive calls by implementing your own stack.

However you can start implementing using a recursiove algorithm, once it works and it is a suited algo, then try to convert to a non recursive implementation

**3. if possible avoid objects**

if you want the fastest, the now it becomes ugly!

A tuppel array  can either be stored in as array of class Point(x,y) or probably faster,
as array of int:
Example: 
(1,2), (2,3), (3,4) can be stored as array: (1,2,2,3,3,4)
This needs much less memory because an object needs at least 12 bytes (in java).
Less memory becomes faster, when the array are really big, then your structure will hopefully fits in the processor cache, while the objects array does not.

**4. Programming language**

In C it will be faster than in Java.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for more algorithm-based approach to increasing speed. I really want to know a good way to derive the final number I need as output (the maximum number of "satisfied tuples)

Answer (score 0):

Maximum cut is a special case of your problem, so I doubt you have a quadratic algorithm for it.  (Maximum cut is NP-complete and it corresponds to the case where every tuple (A,B) also appears in reverse as (B,A) the same number of times.)

The best strategy for you to try here is "branch and bound."  It's a variant of the straightforward recursive search you've probably already coded up.  You keep track of the value of the best solution you've found so far.  In each recursive call, you check whether it's even possible to beat the best known solution with the choices you've fixed so far.

One thing that may help (or may hurt) is to "probe":  for each as-yet-unfixed item, see if putting that item on one of the two sides leads only to suboptimal solutions; if so, you know that item needs to be on the other side.

Another useful trick is to recurse on items that appear frequently both as the first element and as the second element of your tuples.

You should pay particular attention to the "bound" step --- finding an upper bound on the best possible solution given the choices you've fixed.

Comment: This seems like it would be very time consuming. Is this the fastest way to solve this problem?